# Process.Start("explorer.exe"); won't bring back taskbar

Tags: c#, winforms, process, taskmanager

As of right now, I am working on a mock up OS via WinForms to use as a prop for movies.
Upon running the application, it kills explorer.exe so that you can't accidentally have the windows task bar show up during a shoot. The issue is, upon closing the mock OS I would like for explorer.exe to be started up again. However, `Process.Start("explorer.exe");` brings up an explorer window, and does not re-instate the window taskbar.

I know for a fact, that task manager is more than capable of bringing back the window taskbar via typing "explorer.exe" under a new task, though I've had no luck finding command line arguments to pass to task manager.

**Edit:**
I'm running under Windows 7. As well, I'm going pretty in depth with this mock OS. I'm taking control of quite a few key presses that Windows uses. For this reason, I kill explorer.exe so that I can use key presses such as "Alt-Tab" and display a mock app switcher, etc. The app already runs in full screen, but it is still possible to have the underlying Windows GUI pop back up. I am essentially replacing explorer.exe with my own mock up explorer. Upon closing my custom explorer, I can't seem to get the regular Windows GUI to come back by launching explorer.exe via `Process.Start();`.

Comment: Why not simply run fullscreen?

Comment: I'm running under windows 7, however, the mock OS will have to be built to work with any version of windows.

Comment: See the answer [about how to make the winform the topmost item](http://stackoverflow.com/q/118130/1518265), which hides the taskbar...

Comment: Create a full screen window and leave Explorer alone http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/08/01/10438543.aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4279359/454437):

Try

```
Process.Start(Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "explorer.exe"));
```

It appears you must specify the full path to explorer to get the taskbar back.

Comment: Thanks. it works perfectly. Can i run only my app without explorer when logging on? Sorry for my extra question

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://superuser.com/questions/644459/how-to-launch-the-windows-explorer-shell-after-starting-with-a-different-one):

> Explorer must see some fulfilled conditions to launch as shell:
>
> 1. Explorer must not run (which includes Control Panel, for instance)
> 2. Explorer must see it is the actual shell - hence you need to replace that value before launching explorer.exe (could change it back a few seconds later)
> 3. Sometimes it seems (on newer Windows versions) it depends on the process that launches explorer.exe - if it is "known" to explorer.exe -- I don't have any more details for this part though (and you couldn't change it, unfortunately)