# Start explorer.exe without creating a window C#

Tags: c#, windows, process

I have a program that restarts `explorer.exe` 
Here is my code for killing `explorer.exe`

```
Process[] process = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer.exe");

foreach (Process theprocess in process) {
    theprocess.Kill();
}
```

The following code work successfully and stops `explorer.exe`
Here is my code for starting `explorer.exe`

```
Process.Start("explorer");
```

This also works, but it also creates a Windows Explorer window as well as starting the `explorer.exe` process.

My question is, how can I start `explorer.exe` without creating a Windows Explorer window?Immediately closing the explorer window could also be considered as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programatically restart windows explorer process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565405/how-to-programatically-restart-windows-explorer-process)

Note: take the answer from Chuck Rostance as it seems more complete and to your likeness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to start explorer without opening a window, but you can use the `ShellWindows` interface from `SHDocVW.dll` to enumerate explorer windows [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13464352/712649) and then close the window as it pops up:

```
// Kill explorer
Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
foreach (Process p in procs)
{
    p.Kill();
}

// Revive explorer
Process.Start("explorer.exe");

// Wait for explorer window to appear
ShellWindows windows;
while ((windows = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows()).Count == 0)
{
    Thread.Sleep(50);
}

foreach (InternetExplorer p in windows)
{
    // Close explorer window
    if(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p.FullName.ToLower()) == "explorer")
        p.Quit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the explorer is not running, it is enough to call the full path to explorer.exe:

```cs
Process.Start(
    Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "explorer.exe"
    )
);
```

This will only open a window when the explorer is already running, otherwise it just opens the taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

I found a much nicer solution to this after encountering an issue where the taskbar would not always appear when starting explorer:

```
Process.Start(Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "explorer.exe"));
```

If you specify the full path like this, it will not create a window and will only load the taskbar **if explorer is not already running**.

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18262128/808417).